# Angular 2\4 SPA with many html pages

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, architecture

I've started learning angular2\4 for combine it with my ASP-net core application and after two days of understanding ngModules and etc. don't imagine how to create for example:
Application witch have 3 layer of user expiriens

- 1) Employee layer witch have own big module witch contains many
  bussines logic end etc. about 40-50 components
- 2) Client layer same as sentence higher
- 3) Bussines partners layer same thing...

I afraid that my main module witch load in index.html will very heavy size and it will affect on performance
is it possible to create 3 index-pages where user will redirect after authorization based on roles end etc. ( on server side)
Can someone explain me or show me an example GitHub project I haven't found like it many projects which have only one page and simple logic.
Or maybe I have a wrong imagination based on MVC Pattern.

Comment: `index.html` is only a facade for angular to load its many many other pages / templates really.

Comment: use lazy load for modules

Comment: @YounesM okey, but how to manipulate it ? How to configure  that behavior

Comment: You'll have to use angular routing to load the pages you need to.

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi all child component mark as lazy ? Is it true solution ? (I am not dispute )

Comment: https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/lazy-loading-module.html

Comment: @federico scamuzzi  thank you a lot. that article helps me to find a good direction in search